# Error while installing cocoapods

Tags: ruby, xcode5, cocoapods

This is happening:

```
Mac:~ Swanros$ sudo gem install cocoapods
+Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Users/Swanros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.0/ext RUBYLIBDIR=/Users/Swanros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.0/ext
/Users/Swanros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 9 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/Swanros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/Swanros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /Users/Swanros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Swanros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Swanros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.0/ext/xcodeproj/gem_make.out
Mac:~ Swanros$
```

How could I solve this? I'm running OS X Mavericks with Xcode 5 Command Line Tools already installed.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve just released xcodeproj 0.14.1 which contains a fix for this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/blob/0.14.1/CHANGELOG.md.

It should work if you try it again, or you can install the xcodeproj gem first and then try again:

```
$ sudo gem install xcodeproj
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: And you’re sure it was installing 0.14.1? Can you please paste/gist the output? As a workaround, you should be able to first install the ‘rake’ gem and then install ‘xcodeproj’ again: `$ sudo gem install rake`

Comment: @OscarSwanros same error, but this computer looks like have installed cocoapods-core before, just can't use the pod commend. I'm wonder how to clean the computer first

Answer (score 0):

After updating Xcode 5 to Xcode 5.0.1, cocoapods can be installed successfully